# setter and getter method for enumerator c++

Tags: c++, enums, setter, getter

I have the following code, and I am trying to write a getter and setter method for for the enumerator. Can someone please correct my code because after many attempts I still get errors. Thanks for any help with this!

```
///in the header file

    class Car{

    private:    

        enum weight{small, medium, large};
    public:


      Car();


      int getWeight() const; 



      void setWeight(weight w);

    };
////// in the car.cpp file
//default constructor
Car::Car(){

    weight =small;

}

      weight Car::getWeight() const{
        return weight;
      }



      void Car::setWeight(weight w){
        weight = w;
      }
```

Comment: Please post the error. I'm assuming the error is because `getWeight` is declared as returning an `int` but defined as returning `weight`.

Comment: You are getting errors, but.. Why didn't you post them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem 1:

```
enum weight{small, medium, large};
```

is the declaration of a type, not a variable. After this point you can make variables of type `weight` which you can set and get. With

```
enum weight
{
    small, medium, large
};
weight mWeight;
```

you now have a class member , `mWeight`, that you can use with the getters and setters.

But it won't do you much good yet.

Problem 2:

`weight` is `private`, so no one outside the class can see and use this type, making it impossible for `void setWeight(weight w);` the caller can't make a `weight` to pass into the function.

Easily solved by moving the definition of `enum weight` to the public block and then swapping the order of the `public` and `private` blocks so that `weight` is visible to everyone in the class that needs it.

```
class Car
{
public:
    enum weight
    {
        small, medium, large
    };


    Car();

    int getWeight() const;

    void setWeight(weight w);

private:
    weight mWeight;
};
```

Problem 3:

There is a mismatch between

```
int getWeight() const;
```

and

```
weight Car::getWeight() const
```

Seems likely that the correct version returns weight, so

```
class Car
{
public:
    enum weight
    {
        small, medium, large
    };


    Car();

    weight getWeight() const;

    void setWeight(weight w);

private:
    weight mWeight;


};
```

Problem 4:

There is no such thing as `weight`. There is only Zuul. Sorry. Only `Car::weight`, so until the compiler knows a function is part of `Car`, you need to be explicit.

```
weight Car::getWeight() const{
    return weight;
  }
```

needs to become

```
Car::weight Car::getWeight() const{
    return weight;
  }
```

Side note: When you have setters and getters with no restrictions you might as well make the variables `public`. The entire point of making a member variable `private` is to protect the state of the object. If any outsider can change a variable willy-nilly without the object being aware, you wind up with hard to trace bugs.

It's not so important in a trivial case such as above, but what if you have a class with a counter and when that counter reaches 42 something important is supposed to happen. And then some joker comes along and uses this setter

```
void setImportantNumber(int val)
{
    importantNumber = val;
}
```

to set the value to 43? Encapsulation didn't do anyone much good because the setter violated encapsulation.

This on the other hand

```
void setImportantNumber(int val)
{
    if (val) < 42)
    {
        importantNumber = val;
    }
    else if (val == 42)
    {
        importantNumber = 0;
        doSomethingImportant();
    }
    else
    {
        cerr << "I'm afraid I can't let you do that, Dave.\n"
    }
}
```

prevents some amount of foolishness.

Answer (score 0):

With the information posted above I changed the code as shown below and it worked. Thanks!

```
//Car.h:    
 enum weight
    {
        small, medium, large
    };


class Car{
 private:
   weight mWeight;

 public:
  Car();
  weight getWeight() const;
};


//Car.cpp file
    Car::Car(){    
    mWeight =  large;

}

weight Car::getWeight() const{
    return mWeight;
 }
```